# Volume Histogram not showing up on candlestick chart?

Tags: tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

Using the following code, I get the below chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HELLO</title>
    <!-- Include the lightweight-charts library directly from CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/lightweight-charts/dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.production.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            
            // Specify the ID of the div where you want to load the chart
            var chartDivId = 'chart-container';

            // Create the chart inside the specified div
            var chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(chartDivId, {
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                layout: {
                    background: {
                        type: 'solid',
                        color: '#000000',
                    },
                    textColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
                },
                grid: {
                    vertLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
                    },
                    horzLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.5)',
                    },
                },
                crosshair: {
                    mode: LightweightCharts.CrosshairMode.Normal,
                },
                rightPriceScale: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)',
                },
                timeScale: {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(197, 203, 206, 0.8)',
                    timeVisible: true,
                    secondsVisible: true,
                },
            });

            // Create the candlestick series
            var candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({
                upColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                downColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                borderDownColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                borderUpColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                wickDownColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                wickUpColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
            });

            // Create the volume series
            var volumeSeries = chart.addHistogramSeries({
                color: '#26a69a',
                priceFormat: {
                    type: 'volume',
                },
                priceScaleId: '',
            });
            volumeSeries.priceScale().applyOptions({
                scaleMargins: {
                    top: 0.7,
                    bottom: 0,
                },
            });

            // Function to load chart data from the backend
            async function loadChartData() {

                // Query the localhost:8081/getLatestData endpoint, which returns json.NewEncoder(w).Encode([]types.TOHLCV),
                // wait for the response, then parse the response as json, and then set the newData variable to the response.
                await fetch('http://localhost:8081/getLatestData')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => dataFromBackend = data);

                // Format the (datetime) data to the format that the charting library expects
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/76397648/10018602
                const formattedData = dataFromBackend.map(data => ({
                    time: (new Date(data.time)).getTime() / 1000,
                    open: data.open,
                    high: data.high,
                    low: data.low,
                    close: data.close,
                    volume: data.volume,
                }));

                // Set new data to the candlestick series
                candleSeries.setData(formattedData);

                // Format the (volume) data to the format that the charting library expects
                const formattedVolumeData = dataFromBackend.map(data => ({
                    time: (new Date(data.time)).getTime() / 1000,
                    value: data.volume,
                    color: data.open > data.close ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' : 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                }));

                // Set new data to the volume series
                volumeSeries.setData(formattedVolumeData);
            }

            // Initial load of data
            loadChartData();

            // Set an interval to reload chart data every 5 seconds
            setInterval(loadChartData, 5000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: CurrentOutput]

As you can see, I have no volume histogram at the bottom of the chart as the code would suggest.

The data being delivered from the backend indeed has volume in it (using Golang for the backend):

```
// Struct used when importing TOHLCV data from CSV file
type TOHLCV struct {
    DateTime time.Time
    Open     float64
    High     float64
    Low      float64
    Close    float64
    Volume   float64
}
```

```
...
{2024-01-09 19:25:00 -0500 EST 473.94 474 473.94 474 10}
{2024-01-09 19:30:00 -0500 EST 473.95 473.96 473.93 473.96 6}
{2024-01-09 19:35:00 -0500 EST 473.99 473.99 473.99 473.99 5}
{2024-01-09 19:40:00 -0500 EST 474 474.01 473.94 473.95 16}
{2024-01-09 19:45:00 -0500 EST 473.89 473.89 473.81 473.81 150}
{2024-01-09 19:50:00 -0500 EST 473.83 473.83 473.83 473.83 1}
{2024-01-09 19:55:00 -0500 EST 473.77 473.83 473.77 473.79 142}
```

I have already referenced these pages but still cannot get the volume histogram to show up. Any other ideas?

https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/series-types#histogram

https://jsfiddle.net/TradingView/cnbamtuh/

https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/how_to/price-and-volume